# nodejs fs.createWriteStream gives error exactly after 242 files

Tags: node.js, fs

I am generating snapshots from a canvas to be later joined to create a video. The fs.createWriteStream works fine for 242 files, but gives error while creating any file after 242.

Here is the code I am using

```
for(var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++){
     var out = fs.createWriteStream("frame-" + i +".png");
}
```

The above code works perfectly fine till index 241. Exactly at index 242 everytime it gives the error

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: EMFILE, open '~/project/app/frames/frame-242.png'
```

Is it an OS related limitation? I am using Mac OS. Is it because that we can't open more than a limited no of files to write :(
How do I solve this issue to have files which could be hundreds in numbers?

Thanks
Parag

Comment: Do you close the stream when not required anymore ? Do you need the streams to be open simoustanely?

Comment: As above, `EMFILE` means too many open files. You need to close your streams.

Comment: Yes, even if I use out.close(); after writing the file it gives me the following error events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: EBADF, write

Answer (score 0):

Calling

```
out.end()
```

does the magick. As advised by the helpful community and a bit of research I figured out that the function to close the stream is end()